# Find the Blazor component class corresponding to a given path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor server app, how can I find the class (return as `Type`) of the razor component that matches a given path (in `string`, say `"/controller/action"`)? I don't want to navigate to the actual page; I only wish to find the corresponding class and perform some reflection-type stuff with it. It appears to me that the way Blazor handles route is very different from that of MVC and I couldn't quite find any documentation that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully studying the source code provided by agua from mars, I came up with the following solution. First step is to obtain the `Router` object created by the Blazor framework, and I do so by using `CascadingValue` in my `App.razor`:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" @ref="router">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="@router">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                ...
            </RouteView>
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
         ...
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    private Router router;
}
```

So now in any page of my app I can obtain the `Router` object using `CascadingParameterAttribute`. Next comes reflection (since a lot of things involved here are defined as `internal`):

```cs
public Type Find(Router router, string path) {
    var assm = typeof(Router).Assembly;
    var routes = typeof(Router).GetProperty("Routes", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(router);
    var type = assm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "RouteContext");
    var context = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new[] { path });
    routes.GetType().GetMethod("Route", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(routes, new[] { context });
    return type.GetProperty("Handler").GetValue(context) as Type;
}
```

And this function achieves exactly what I need.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but could you provide an example of usage?

Comment: Well, I used to use these code in the following scenario: in the navigation menu, where I have a bunch of links to the various pages of my site, I create a custom `menuItem` component which, given only the link url, it locates the corresponding page component, automatically generates title text (by a custom attribute on my page), and decides whether to show the link based on authorization settings of that page.

Comment: But later I thought, hey, why don't I just pass the page type to my `menuItem`, and generates the link url based on the first route setting of that page instead? This way I can avoid using the `Find` function given above, which uses reflections to access non-public members (not exactly good practice). So eventual I don't use these codes anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to find all components with a [`RouteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) attribute. `@page` directive are transformed into `RouteAttribute`.

```
var pageTypeList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
.GetTypes()
.Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute)) != null);
```

Comment: Looks like we're on the right direction; however, in my use case, it is possible that `@page` templates contain parameters. I could try to write my own parser to compare the templates with the given path, but is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: No, but when you get page type, you can query for the attribute value

Comment: That can inspired you : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4a7bf75e89e3dfe7264a641ed041f50788d28d20/src/Components/Components/src/Routing/RouteTableFactory.cs

Comment: Aha, that most certainly looks like what I'm looking for. I'll study those code and see if I can figure things out. Thanks.

Comment: I just came up with a solution; check it out if you're interested.

Comment: The issue with your solution it's it can be broken in a next release of blazor because you call non public members and thoses members can be removed or changed. It's more a hack than viable solution. Do you agree ?

Comment: I certainly do agree, but for now since the built-in parsing mechanism is all non-public, I don't really have a better option. Writing my own parser is equally non-viable as the template syntax is also subject to change.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is more of a comment for the accepted answer, but I don't have the rep.

**TL;DR** - `RouteData.PageType` will solve the original problem for most simple use cases. If you are experiencing inconsistent results with this - use an updated version of Mu-Tsun Tsai's answer, clarified below.

I had a similar situation that lead me here. I used [Mu-Tsun Tsai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60165714/13350243). While I was doing this, I found that the `RouteData.PageType` provides a similar value - which probably works in most simple cases.

Unfortunately, my case needed that PageType in order to determine if the navigation was valid - and if not, then navigate to a default page. I suspect that the nested navigation caused a race condition, that wasn't picked up by `RouteData.PageType` - for some reason, it returned the PageType of the referring page, instead of the PageType of the destination page in limited and inconsistent circumstances.

I ultimately reverted to Mu-Tsun Tsai's answer because it is able to determine the type based on the destination page.

**Caveats**

- The use of reflection has already broken the original answer. An update needs to be made to use `routes.GetType().GetMethod("Route", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(routes, new[] { context });`
- The path needs to be relative or it will not detect the page type

Comment: While trying to update my code-base that used this solution, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63225118/13350243) by @enet. It removes the need for using the fragile reflection. I think that solution is the best for reliability and maintainability, and works well with Blazor components. I've already incorporated it into my code with minimal changes from what has been pasted in these answers.