# How to access current route using Blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I have an ASP(dot)NET web app that has a simple navbar, I am trying to use a Blazor component that will alter the navbar and increase the width of the left border if the page happens to be the active page. So far I am using a switch statement that will switch based on the current page which is represented by a string. My problem is that I cannot find a way to programmatically find the current URL that the site is on. I have searched up this question multiple times and each solution has not worked for me, using HttpContext has not worked either.

```
switch (CurrUrl)
{
case "Index":
    <header>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main-menu">
                    <li id="CurPage">Home</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">Shop</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">FAQ</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    break;
case "Shop":
    <header>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                    <li id="CurPage">Shop</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">FAQ</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    break;
case "FAQ":
    <header>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                    <li Class="menu-item">Shop</li>
                    <li id="CurPage">FAQ</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    break;
case "About":
    <header>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">Shop</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">FAQ</li>
                    <li id="CurPage">About</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    break;
}

@code {
    string CurrUrl = null;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to access current route using Blazor component

This title is misleading and you should change it. You can't access the
the current route in order to do that task, as the current route does
not exist yet

> I have searched up this question multiple times and each solution has
> not worked for me, using HttpContext has not worked either.

Again, the solution is not by using the current route as no route has
already been created. Your components are not yet created, so no route
is available

HttpContext is not available in Blazor, most of the time, if at all...

Solution:

Add this code to the MainLayout component

1. Define a property of type Type. This property will be populated with
   the Type ( component) that is going to be created
2. You can retrieve the type of the component from the OnParametersSet
   method of the MainLayout component
3. When you start your project, the Type is Index
   (Note that it is returned in the form: `<projectname>.Pages.Index)`
4. If you type in your browser the url of your app + "/counter",
   as for instance: `https://localhost:44373/counter`, you'll get
   `<projectname>.Pages.Counter`

---

```
 @code{

     public Type PageType { get; set; }

     protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
    
       PageType = (this.Body.Target as RouteView)?.RouteData.PageType;

       Console.WriteLine("This is your type (current type)" + 
                                                      PageType);
    }
  }
```

At the top of the MainLayout.razor file the `<NavMenu />` is instantiated. Add to it an attribute parameter named PageType, as follows:

```
<NavMenu PageType="@PageType" />
```

The `PageType` on the left side should be defined in the NavMenu component. As you can see it is bound to the `PageType` property defined in MainLayout.

Now you should define the parameter property named `PageType` in NavMenu like this:

### NavMenu.razor

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Type PageType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you have the current Type (component) available in your NavMenu
component, and you can use it as you please.

It is essential that you understand how components are rendered... which comes first, next etc. And much much more...

But hey, you're going to have tough time managing your task... The following code snippet demonstrates, very roughly that what you intend to do is workable( My code is fine and does the job, and the issues you're going to have are not related to it).

### NavMenu.razor

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
       
    @switch (PageType.ToString())
    {
        case "BlazorApp4.Pages.Index":
            @*<header>
                    <div>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="main-menu">
                                <li id="CurPage">Home</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">Shop</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">FAQ</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>*@

            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
            break;
        case "Shop":
            <header>
                <div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="main-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                            <li id="CurPage">Shop</li>
                            <li class="menu-item">FAQ</li>
                            <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            break;
        case "FAQ":
            <header>
                <div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="main-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                            <li Class="menu-item">Shop</li>
                            <li id="CurPage">FAQ</li>
                            <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            break;
        case "About":
            <header>
                <div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="main-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                            <li class="menu-item">Shop</li>
                            <li class="menu-item">FAQ</li>
                            <li id="CurPage">About</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            break;
    }
</div>
```

The code above is going to display the default links to the default template pages, when you start your page. (Index page). Comment out the code in the `case "BlazorApp4.Pages.Index:`, and uncomment your code (...) located under `case "BlazorApp4.Pages.Index":`

Lo and behold, total darkness... here comes your pains...work hard...good luck.

Comment: I will heed your warnings and read up on component rendering and just obtain a better grasp on Blazor itself. Still new to learning Blazor, I just always read how Blazor is supposed to be a substitute for javascript and wanted to test out setting up an active page using Blazor instead. Did not know the true work that would be involved in this task, but I like a challenge and look foward to achieving my results. Thank you!

Comment: Blazor is definitely not supposed to be a substitute for javascript...where did you read this ? The way to thank folks in statckoverflow is to up-vote and accept their answers.

Comment: Good answer except for "This title is misleading and you should change it".  When asking a question, the asker usually doesn't know what it is that he doesn't know, so has to specify what he intends.   The title perfectly captures the intention, and matches the search that will bring many others to this answer.

Answer (score 11):

I used

```
<CascadingValue Name="RouteData" Value="routeData"> ... </CascadingValue>
```

in App.Razor to make de current routeData available to all components as a cascading parameter.

```cs
[CascadingParameter(Name = "RouteData")]
public RouteData? RouteData { get; set; }
```

RouteData has a property 'PageType' which contains the type of the currently routed Page-component.

Comment: are there any downsides to exposing the RouteData like this? Just wondering, since they do not expose it themselves :)

Comment: Is there any way to access the route data in a AuthorizationHandler on Blazor client

Comment: Downside here is that the RouteData.PageType is only available on Blazor Server not WASM :/ Any idea how to get it for client version?

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current URL from the navigation manager.

```
@page "/navigate"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code {
   string CurrUrl = null;
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       CurrUrl = NavigationManager.Uri.ToString();
   }
}
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers)

Comment: Wait, is this a asp.net core Razor application with a Blazor component? If so, then I'm not sure how to this.

Comment: You don't need `ToString()` since `Uri` already is a `string`.