# Migrating RouteData Usage from ASP.NET to Blazor MAUI: Handling 'Page' Definition Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, maui, blazor-server-side, maui-blazor

I'm facing an issue with the following code in Blazor:

```
obj_arv.isi = Page.RouteData.Values("idi");
```

This code works well in `ASP.NET`, but when I try to use it in `Blazor MAUI`, it gives an error stating that `'Page' does not contain a definition for 'RouteData.'`

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your code `Page.RouteData.Values` is based on the `.NET framework`, which doesn't apply to `Asp.net core`. In blazor, we use  `Parameter attribute` to achieve this.

For more information, you can check: [Route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#route-parameters).

And there is a similar problem, you can check: [How to access current route using Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224636/how-to-access-current-route-using-blazor-component).

**Update:**

> Can you write the code I wrote in Blazor ?

In the following example, the text optional parameter assigns the value of the route segment to the component's Text property. If the segment isn't present, the value of Text is set to fantastic.

```
@page "/route-parameter-2/{text?}"

<h1>Blazor is @Text!</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = Text ?? "fantastic";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write the code I wrote in Blazor ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. :)